# How to open any page when you click on <div>

Tags: html

How to made, that when you click on `<div id="fb_logo"></div>` it's open any page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="fb_logo target="_blank""><a href="Your page link"></a></div>
```

Here is jsfiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/wuq0tqgp/1/

Comment: target _blank  is html link property use it inside <a> tag



http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by placing the div tag inside the link  tag

```
<a href="http://YourPageLink.com/" target="_blank">

<div id="fb_logo"></div>

</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/djsreeraj/n5n5c44y/1/

Here is the snippet:

```css
#fb_logo{
  background:#ccc;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#fb_logo a{
  display:block;
  text-indent:999px;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank"><div id="fb_logo"></div></a>
```

Comment: I try this, but it's mistake, then you hover a div, then you can click and after text